# Error al crear una aplicación de nuxt 3 | no se pueden instalar los node_modules

Tags: javascript, ubuntu, vue3, nuxt

Buen día colegas,estoy tratando de crear una aplicación en nuxt para comenzar a aprender las nuevas funcionalidades, pero tengo los siguientes errores, ya llevo dos días tratando de resolver este problema.

`npm install npm@latest -g`

Hasta aquí todo bien, pero el error es cuando entro a la carpeta del proyecto

`npm install`

[image: Error 1]

Investigando hay una [solución](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76478238/8150485) donde podemos importar de manera manual.

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  // My Nuxt config
})
```

> Agrego la importación > manual > borro los node_modules > npm install

Pero, ahora me da otro error,

[image: Error 2]

Esto es lo que tengo instalado:

```
OS: Ubuntu 22:04
Node 18.17.1
Npm 9.8.1
```

Ya reinstalé mi versión de Nodejs, probé con n y nvm, tampoco funcionó y las desinstalé completamente, actualmente solo tengo una versión de node, siento que el problema va por la versión de node,ya hice downgrade a diferentes versiones desde la 16 hasta la 20 con nvm y no funciona,en windows 11 intenté crear el proyecto y todo bien, pero ya no me quedan ideas de que puede ser.

He creado proyecto con Nuxt 2, vue3 con vite, y todo bien, este error nada más es para nuxt 3, me urge, porque tengo que empezar un proyecto con esta versión

Comment: Entendido con lo de las imagenes, y no no funcionó las soluciones de esas respuestas.